# Merge two comma delimited strings in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure

I have two comma-delimited strings as below:

```
stringA "a,b,c,d"
stringB "w,x,y,z"
```

How can I merge the strings as below in **clojure**:

```
stringResult "aw,bx,cy,dz"
```

Note: The comma-delimited values are same in number for both **stringA** and **stringB**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the comma-separated items can have multiple characters:

```
(defn combine
  [stringA stringB]
  (let [seqA (clojure.string/split stringA #",")
        seqB (clojure.string/split stringB #",")
        combined (map str seqA seqB)]
    (clojure.string/join "," combined)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(.replace (apply str (map str stringA stringB)) ",," ",")
;=> "aw,bx,cy,dz"
```

See A. Webb's comment below.

Comment: This works only if each comma separated value has length of exactly one. Otherwise its a disaster. Anyway, I'm not sure we should be supporting zero-effort questions even in our beautiful little corner.